# Does Firebase support overwritten setter methods?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Can you use overwritten setter methods in your Java object (e.g. one that takes a String object and one that takes an int)? if you are going to load and read your object from the Firebase database? Does Firebase know which to use or is it all treated as int/String?

e.g:

```
public void setAppointStartTime(String appointStartTime) {
    this.appointStartTime = appointStartTime;
}

public void setAppointStartTime(int minutes) {
    this.appointStartTime = String.format("%02d",((minutes - (minutes % 60)) / 60)) + ":" + (String.format("%02d",(minutes%60)));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase SDK follows a JavaBean pattern for determining the properties in a class. JavaBeans properties are of a single type, since their getter method will have a single return type.

As far as I recall, your example setters will lead to the client generating an error about not knowing the type of the `appointStartTime` property.

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#basic_write):

> For basic write operations, you can use `setValue()` to save data to a
>   specified reference, replacing any existing data at that path. You can
>   use this method to:
>
> - Pass types that correspond to the available JSON types as follows:
>
>   - String
>   - Long
>   - Double
>   - Boolean
>   - Map
>   - List
>   - Pass a
>       custom Java object, if the class that defines it has a default
>       constructor that takes no arguments and has public getters for the
>       properties to be assigned.

Comment: So does Firebase keep track of the variable type? e.g. String, Long, Double? I thought from looking at my json it was all String.

Comment: Yes, I just checked my database and I can store numbers as both strings and longs. As for other types, you should note that lists, for example, will be converted to objects in Firebase with the item indices serving as keys.